# Where can I find deleted packages from debian main pool?

Tags: debian, package-management

I'm in need for an older version of debootstrap(1.0.93 to be specific). I can't find it in the [pool](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/debootstrap/). The newer version(0.97) is giving some issues. The older one worked fine. I'm pretty sure that I downloded 0.93 from the main pool. Don't they keep a copy of every version? I can't find them [here](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/debootstrap/). Any other place to look for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get debootstrap v1.0.93 from snapshot.debian.org, but be warned that the site does not support encryption so you should verify your downloads.

http://snapshot.debian.org/package/debootstrap/1.0.93%2Bnmu3/

If the site goes down (which it does occasionally), check the Internet Archive's Wayback Machine for a cached version of its contents.

Comment: Great. That'll do. But I didn't understand the warning part. Why should I verify that? What's the risk?

Comment: Don't they provide checksum in snapshot site?

Comment: I just noticed they have listed checksum with the file. I believe one can use that too. Right?

Comment: Okay. Then virustotal is the best solution.

Comment: VirusTotal for what? How about using Linux tools to verify the checksum?

Comment: I noticed one more thing. The checksums are available as plain text(on the webpage itself) which can be copied and pasted into terminal for verification(no download needed). As we are not downloading any checksum file, there is hardly any chance of malicious modification during transit. Incase of unavailability of this direct text, a scan for malicious modification is a must(thanks to http connection).